# How do I copy data from several columns in Google Sheets into a different column using conditional data from a separate column?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a form which fills a Google Sheet.
So question 1 in the form has some multiple choices: "one", "two", and "three".
Depending on the choice, I would like to use data from the questions that follow to create a text in a separate column.

For example:
Answer for Question 2: Apple.

Answer for Question 3: Banana.

Answer for Question 4: Watermelon.

Answer for Question 5: Strawberry.

Answer for Question 6: Passion Fruit.

Answer for Question 7: Blackberry.

Answer for Question 8: Pineapple.

Answer for Question 9: Mango.

(each question would be in a different column)

Column 10 would have the text below:

If the user answers "one" in question 1, I would like to have column 10 with the following data:
" He likes 'Apple' with 'Banana', and 'Watermelon'."

If the user answers "two" in question 1, I would like to have column 10 with the following data:
" He likes 'Strawberry' with 'Passion Fruit', and 'Blackberry'."

If the user answers "three" in question 1, I would like to have column 10 with the following data:
" He likes 'Pineapple' and 'Mango'."

Answer (score 0):

If you are prepared to keep copying down each time a new response is received then:

```
="He likes "&choose(B2,C2&" with "&D2&", and "&E2,F2&" with "&G2&", and "&H2,I2&" and "&J2)
```

might suit (assuming `1` will serve for "one" etc and the singe inverted commas are not part of the required output).